# отрисовка полей через map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Пытаюсь отрисовать блок с комментариями ,но получаю ошибку undefined.Как происходит так что title,author,description получается отрисовать ,а массив commnets в этот момент undefined

```
export default class ArticlestoreServices{
    data = [
        {
            id:1,
            title:'most popular language in 2019',
            description:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam harum distinctio necessitatibus eius voluptates. Voluptatem, excepturi necessitatibus. Recusandae fugiat sequi necessitatibus veritatis, hic vero molestias iure? Possimus iusto soluta facere a, nesciunt sunt reprehenderit et repellat odio. Libero, eveniet exercitationem. Nostrum quis odit unde nihil, delectus soluta aut, deserunt qui quia neque, laboriosam aliquid maxime id. Magnam, ipsa officia eum commodi molestiae iure ea natus praesentium eligendi, explicabo totam quis, voluptatem impedit itaque excepturi error est tempora magni eaque corrupti at voluptatibus? Atque autem dolorem laboriosam error alias necessitatibus omnis iste, nulla aliquam dolores mollitia optio aperiam sit delectus deleniti.',
            author:'John',
            comments:[
              {
              name:'asd',
              desc:'asda'
              },
              {
                name:'asdad',
                desc:'asdada'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id:2,
            title:'angularVSvue',
            description:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae eius veritatis quod iste ducimus suscipit nostrum aut alias dicta placeat rem doloribus consectetur modi fugit, dolor praesentium quidem tempore sint eveniet minima eum quasi vitae est dolores. Incidunt, maxime a commodi placeat necessitatibus nemo fuga excepturi reprehenderit culpa libero in sapiente itaque tempore explicabo quo ab? Soluta, debitis fuga necessitatibus numquam dolore officia vero praesentium nulla ducimus labore. Nihil fuga natus cum hic ad totam laudantium omnis, enim veniam ducimus nobis accusantium cupiditate earum eum, eveniet possimus amet. Voluptas culpa deleniti necessitatibus nesciunt placeat itaque perferendis consequatur, eos quam enim.',
            author:'Steve'
        }
    ]
    getArticles() {
        return this.data;
      }
}




import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {withArticlestoreService} from '../hoc'


class ArticlePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {article:[],
        };
      }
    componentDidMount(){
        const {articlestoreService} = this.props;
        const data = articlestoreService.getArticles();



        const currentArticle = data.find(
            article=> article.id === +this.props.match.params.id
            );

            this.setState({
                article:currentArticle,

            })
            console.log(this.state)
        }

      render(){

          return (

              <div>
             <h1> title:{this.state.article.title}</h1>
             <h2>{this.state.article.description}</h2>
             <h3>author:{this.state.article.author}</h3>
                <hr/>
             <div className="comments">
                <ul>
                {
            this.state.article.comments.map((name,desc)=>{
                return(
                    <li>
                    <h1>asdasd</h1>
                    {/* <h2>{desc.desc}</h2> */}
                    </li>
                )
            })
        }
                </ul>


             </div>
             </div>
          );
      }
}
const mapStateToProps = ({articles}) => {
    return { articles};
    };



export default withArticlestoreService()(connect(mapStateToProps)(ArticlePage));
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошиблись в функции map:

```
arr.map(callback(item, i, arr))
```

- item – очередной элемент массива.
- i – его номер.
- arr – массив, который перебирается.

Поэтому пытаясь вызвать на порядковом номере i.desc вы получаете `undefined`.

```
        this.state.article.comments.map((item, i)=>{
            return(
                <li>
                <h1>asdasd</h1>
                <h2>{item.name} - {item.desc}</h2>
                </li>
            )
        })
```

Comment: @alex-karas,не помогло ,но добавил проверку this.state.article.comments!==undefined? и заработало,но так и не понял каким образом данные чуть выше в коде рендерятся нормально,а для мапа нужно костыль писать...

Comment: @ЛёшаСугуров хм, может из-за пустых данных, которые вы добавляете `this.state = {article:[],};` в конструкторе и он пытается это прорисовать в компонент? Тогда да, comments действительно будут undefined и попытка вызвать на них map вызовет ошибку. Может стоить перенести получение данных в componentWillMount

Answer (score 0):

@alex-karas прав, но мне кажется что Вы хотели провести **destructuring** и забыли обернуть атрибуты до **{}**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { withArticlestoreService } from '../hoc'


class ArticlePage extends Component {
  state = { article: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { articlestoreService, match } = this.props;
    const data = articlestoreService.getArticles();

    const currentArticle = data.find(
      article => article.id === match.params.id
    );

    this.setState({ article: currentArticle })
  }

  render() {
    const { article: { title, description, author } } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> title: {title}</h1>
        <h2>{description}</h2>
        <h3>author: {author}</h3>
        <hr />
        <div className="comments">
          <ul>
            {this.state.article.comments.map((**{ title, name, desc }**, index) => (
              <li **key**={`comment-${index}`}>
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                <h2>{name} - {desc}</h2>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = ({ articles }) => ({ articles });

export default withArticlestoreService()(connect(mapStateToProps)(ArticlePage));
```

З.Ы. не забывайте что нужно добавлять уникальный key когда добавляете элементы из цикла